# Jenkins Build Multiple projects in same repository

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

Previously we had a single monolith in GitLab repository and we used to build project in Jenkins using Jenkinsfile.

Now we are migrating it into multiple microservices and all reside in same GitLab repository. Is it possible to create pipelines for this type of setup or do we need to have each microservice in separate repository. If it is possible please point me to appropriate resources.

Comment: You can create several Jenkinsfile's and create several Projects in Jenkins, each using a different Jenkinsfile.

Answer (score 0):

Each microservice can have its own Jenkinsfile, you have to tell to the Jenkins job the path of the Jenkinsfile if it is not located at the root path.

In your pipeline configuration job choose "Pipeline script from SCM" and set the "Script Path".

To only checkout the microservice you need, you can use in the "SCM" then "Additional Behaviours" the "Check out to a sub-directory" (then if the Jenkinsfile is now at the pseudo root path, you won't need to change the default "Script Path").

Comment: I've used the "Sparse Checkout paths" under "Additional Behaviours" which worked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to create pipelines to build/test/deploy from a single repository.
Use Declarative Pipeline in Jenkins.

You can have your microservices separated in different directories in a single repo and can build them all using a single pipeline using the stages & dir() option in Jenkinsfile. We're building close to 15 components from a single pipeline and push it to it's relevant artifactory from the same job. You can build non-dependent microservice components parallely too.

Documentation --> [Jenkins Pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/),[Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/)

Comment: We use scripted pipeline instead of declarative ones as they provide more flexibility.